# Matlab integration

Tags: integration, matlab

I have a graph. I need to integrate between certain x values. I don't have a function for the graph, the curve came from an array of x values and y values. How do I  do this?

Comment: Look up the [interp1](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) function, choice will give you a function that you can then use with [quad](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/quad.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to simply apply some of the basic techniques you (should have) learned in calculus. If you have two data vectors, $x$ and $y$, then you have enough data to apply the midpoint method, the trapezoid method, or any other such method.

For instance, the trapezoid method basically says that the area under the curve between two points $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$ is approximately equal to $y_n(x_{n+1}-x_{n})+\frac12 (y_{n+1}-y_{n})(x_{n+1}-x_n)$, which is equal to the area of the rectangle formed by the height of $x_n$, and adding the area of the triangle whose base is the distance between $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$ and whose hypotenuse is the line segment connecting $y_n$ and $y_{n+1}$. This can be converted to Matlab easily:

```
n = length(x);
S = 0;
for i=1:n-1
    S = S + 1/2*(y(i+1)+y(i))*(x(i+1)-x(i));
end
```

Or, more succinctly and efficiently,

```
dY = y(1:end-1)+y(2:end);
dX = x(2:end)-x(1:end-1);
S = 1/2*sum(dY.*dX);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate it. The problem I have is that i don't want to integrate the entire curve, just from some value a-b. I have over 3000 values. I don't know how to write code that will find the x value start point.

Comment: First you need to ensure that $x$ is in ascending order. If you are sure of this, no problem. If not, do `[x,index] = sort(x); y = y(index);` This will put $x$ in ascending order, and keep the associated values of $y$ with their $x$ counterparts. Then, search the array for the nearest value to $a$, and likewise for $b$. You can do this with `[xa,a_index] = min(abs(x-a));` and likewise for $b$. Finally, pick the sub-vector: `x_prime = x(a_index:b_index); y_prime = y(a_index:b_index);`, and replace `x` and `y` in the code in my answer with `x_prime` and `y_prime`.

Comment: Just to clarify - it is not necessary to do [xa,a_index] = min(abs(x-a)); for the y values - correct?

Comment: Right, because you're trying to find the nearest $x$ values to $a$ and $b$. The associated $y$ values will have the same indices.